# Calculating combinations without repetitions

Tags: combinatorics

So, regarding this assignment, I have to create a team, with three workers and one boss. I have ten people to choose from. That would mean, that it is a question of combinations without repetitions. I know how to calculate it, using the correct formula, and I know the answer is 840. However, it is a multiple choice question, where I have to mark all of the right answers to this question.

$$10\cdot \binom 93\quad \quad 4\cdot \binom {10}4\quad\; \;\;7\cdot \binom {10}3\quad \;\;\; 4\cdot \binom {10}6\quad\; \;\;10\cdot \binom 96\quad \;\;\;7\cdot \binom {10}7$$

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IMTy.png)

According to my teacher, it should only take 5 minutes to calculate all the following possibilities. What am I missing here? I spend 20 minutes calculating them all.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for...there are a lot of relations between binomial symbols.  Were you calculating by hand?  With mechanical assistance, the computations are very fast.

Comment: If, on the other hand, this was an exercise in manipulating binomial coefficients, you can go quite quickly.  For instance $10\times \binom 93 = 10\times \frac {9!}{3!\,6!}=4\times \frac {10!}{4!\,6!}=4\times \binom {10}4=4\times \binom {10}6$ by simple operations.  Or by combinatorics...first choose the captain, then the other three versus first choose your four members, then pick the captain

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be done by hand

Comment: Well, what I just sketched handles three of the cases instantly.  For example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use combinatorial knowledge to judge whether they meet your problem:

- Pick the lead first, then pick $3$ of the remaining $9$ people to be the grunts: $10\binom 93$.
- Pick the $4$ team members first, then pick one of them to be the lead: $\binom{10}4 4$.
- Pick the $3$ grunts first, then pick the lead from among the remaining $7$: $\binom{10}3 7$.
- Send the $6$ non-qualifiers home, then choose the lead from the remaining members: $\binom{10}6 4$.
- Pick the lead first, then send the $6$ non-qualifiers home: $10\binom96$.
- Pick the $7$ non-grunts first, then choose one of them to be lead: $\binom{10}7 7$.

Thus all six options for how to do the selecting will end up with $3$ grunts and $1$ lead. They all should give the same value.

But to confirm that you haven't missed something, you should examine the calculation process. For that you do not need to actually calculate them all out - just confirm that they can all be put in the same form. You need to know two things about the combinatorial symbol $\binom nm$:

- Its expression in terms of factorials: $\binom nm = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$
- and that it is symmetric: $\binom nm = \binom n{n-m}$

By use of the second fact, it becomes immediately obvious that three of your options are identical to the other three:
$$10\binom 93 = 10\binom 96\\4\binom{10}4 = 4\binom{10}6\\7\binom{10}3 = 7\binom{10}7$$
So you only need to check if the first three give the same or different values. For this, you can convert to factorials and do some cancelling:
$$10\binom 93 = 10\frac{9!}{3!6!} = \frac{10!}{3!6!}\\
4\binom{10}4 = 4\frac{10!}{4!6!} = \frac{10!}{3!6!}\\
7\binom{10}3 = 7\frac{10!}{3!7!} = \frac{10!}{3!6!}$$
So all three (and therefore all six) options give the same value. Since one of them is presumably the "correct formula" you used, you can deduce that all six are correct answers.